# Rails geocoding not for a map, not with Google

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, rails-geocoder

I'm using the geocoder gem, which by default uses Google for geocoding. However the Google terms of service do not probably allow usage that does not immediately show on a Google Map. Likewise Bing I think. Is anyone using a geocoding service that is both accurate for U.S. street addresses, and has terms of service that allow use outside of a map?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Bing Maps geocoder without a map if you wish. The only restriction is that you can't show those coordinates on a competitors map such as Google Maps. If this is for a mobile app, Win 8 app, or a public facing website there are free terms of use which you can look into. Mobile and Win 8 allow 50,000 transactions a day (i.e. 1 transaction == 1 geocode requests), public facing websites are allowed 125,000 transactions a year. If this is for an internal application or non-public facing app then you would need to license Bing Maps. You can find more information on licensing here: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/Licensing/licensing.aspx

Comment: Thanks @rbrundritt, this seems very promising. Any idea how we can check the terms that apply to us, if we both serve consumers, and business that serve consumers? (as in a marketplace web application). The licensing information page you provided the link to, seems to take the approach of either one or the other, not both.